# Client Team Foundation Server with Command-Line

Tags: tfs

I'm trying to connect to the Team Foundation Server from command line. 
these are the steps i did to connect:

```
tf eula

tf workspace -new Beta1 -collection:http://myserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection

tf workfold -map $/ScrumProject/JavaSample -workspace:Beta1 /Users/Example

tf get
```

I get this command from 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873092.aspx

the problem is when i write **tf get** i always get this message

"All files up to date." and there are no files that exist in the distention folder.

Massive thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the destination directory `/Users/Example` exist?

Comment: Similarly, do you have a TeamProject called `ScrumProject`, with a folder `JavaSample` in the default collection?

Comment: @Rowland Shaw 
the destination folder D:\TFS_Project and exist

Comment: You make no mention of `D:\TFS_Project` on your `tf workfold` command - what commands did you actually execute?

Comment: there is no problem in map 
D:\TFS>tf workfold -map $/ERP -workspace:Beta1 D:\TFS_Project -login:motaz@KDS,password

Answer (score 0):

When TFS fo a get operation, and if your workspace version is the same, TFS does not replace any file on disk unless the **/all** option is specified.

Also there is **/overwrite** option to forcibly overwrite.

Also when we pass the **/force** option, TFS overwrites all items in the workspace with the latest server version unless you provide a specific version.

so Can you try something like

```
 tf get D:\project\* /version:C111 /overwrite /force
```

Comment: also get this massage
"All files up to date"

Comment: This could be because latest version of all the files are downloaded . There may be  nothing mapped that can be downloaded.Make sure that path used in command exists, if this path does not exist,it will give this message "All files up to date" ... you can just try with /force  switch as it will get the latest version forcefully ..try with only /force ..hope that will help